# кроссбраузерность для ios

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Есть ли бесплатные инструменты что-бы посмотреть как выглядит сайт на ios устройствах ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эмуляторы: [Design.Google](http://design.google.com/), [Symby](http://symby.ru/adaptest/), [Browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com/responsive), [Responsinator](http://www.responsinator.com/), [Quirktools](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/), [Mattkersley](http://mattkersley.com/responsive/), [Jamus](http://www.jamus.co.uk/demos/rwd-demonstrations/), [Screenqueri](http://screenqueri.es/), [Mobiletest](http://mobiletest.me/), [MobiReady](http://ready.mobi/). На любой вкус

Comment: более менее подходит browserstack. Но нет ios 11 а там сейчас жесть творится

Comment: @Andry, тоже нужно было проверить на ios 11, но ничего подходящего не нашел(может быть плохо искал). Если мой ответ хоть чем-нибудь помог, то отметьте решением или поставьте +, пожалуйста:)